# Cache refresh: refresh on each db update?

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4

I would like to get some confirmation about the use of a back end cache.

Imagine that I am a user and I'm requesting a list of events (activities) with autocompletion.
One could say that the response to a request that is being made many times is better of being cached.

However, imagine that I am an organiser of an event and I create a new event.
As an organiser, I want to test if I can find back my newly created event instantly.
If the cache is only refreshed let's say every hour, then it might take some time before the newly created event shows up in the front end.

Obviously this is not the purpose; does this mean that the cache should be refreshed *manually* every time a new event is being uploaded?

Comment: Why you don't just refresh the cache after every event creation, have a look at [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events).

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to your model update event and clear the cache.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Model::updated(function($model_instance)
    {
       // clear cache
    });
}
```

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events

I hope I understood your problem.